# Implementing a personal firewall for Windows, how can I determine what application does a packet belong to?

Tags: windows, security, networking, firewall, ndis

I am going to build a sort of personal firewall for Windows. I've found some articles on this subject on the Net, including some questions here on StackOverflow. But all they mean to control protocols, addresses and ports. It is as well important for me to control on per-application basis. Any suggestions on where to look?

Comment: Um.. you should already know this if you are writing a host based firewall... there are _much_ greater problems you will face.

Comment: +1, one possibility -  "netstat -nop" shows which processes open which sockets, so get the source/target socket from the TCP header and map it to a process.

Comment: yeah you could just use netfilter or even iptables on Linux, for Windows I have no clue, I wouldn't be surprised if you have to reverse engineer the Windows kernel's network subsystem and hook it :/

Comment: netfilter and iptables are *firewalls*, not APIs. Nor do they, AFAIK, do application firewalling - operating only at the network stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GetExtendedTcpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365928(v=VS.85).aspx) with a [`TCP_TABLE_CLASS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366386(v=VS.85).aspx) parameter of `TCP_TABLE_OWNER_MODULE_CONNECTIONS` will give you all the connected endpoints and the [owning process id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366911(v=VS.85).aspx).

You can pass the table row to [GetOwnerModuleFromTcpEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366003(v=VS.85).aspx) to get the [module name and path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366380(v=VS.85).aspx).